# How to calculate expected relative frequency from observed data in python

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution

I have a data sets with mean = 40, sd = 5 with equal class interval of 20 starting with 30, so the first frequency class is (30 -50). I have calculate the expected relative cumulative frequency (in normal distribution) for first class by using the code below

```
scipy.stats.norm.cdf((50-mean)/sd)-scipy.stats.norm.cdf((30-mean)/sd)
```

then how can I calculate the expected value for up to 10 classes by defining the function so that the expected value for second class will be

```
scipy.stats.norm.cdf((70-mean)/sd)-scipy.stats.norm.cdf((50-mean)/sd)
```

Any help on this problem is highly appriciated.

Comment: This question was very difficult to read, and I'm still not sure what you're asking. Do you want to calculate "the expected value" (do you mean the expected frequency in that class?) for those 10 classes: (30..50, 50..70, 70..90, 90..110, ...)? If yes, what's the problem? You already got the first two. Are you asking for help writing a for loop?

Comment: @maxy sorry my english is not so good and yes you understand my question..I did this calculation manually for ten classes. My question is how to make loop for this problem? so that we dont have to do manually for each classes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a simple for loop:

```
cdf = scipy.stats.norm.cdf # just a shortcut
for i in range(10):
    lo = 30 + 20*i
    hi = lo + 20
    freq = cdf((hi-mean)/sd)-cdf((lo-mean)/sd)
    print 'interval', lo, 'to', hi, 'freq', freq
```

or you could calculate it using arrays (also called *vectorized*):

```
start, interval = 30, 20
count = 10
lo = start + numpy.arange(count) * interval
hi = lo + interval
print cdf((hi-mean)/sd)-cdf((lo-mean)/sd)
```

As expected, the higher intervals are far into the tail of the normal distribution and all zero.

If the first method caused you problems, I recommend to search for a generic Python tutorial and work trough it.

Comment: Thank you maxy for your great help :)